# SVN Authentication failed (locally)

Tags: svn, unix

I am using svn+ssh to connect to svn repository, which in turns uses unix usernames and passwords for authentication. Everything works fine.

However, I also have a checked out version of a repository on the same server on which repository is hosted. And when I try to commit changes made to this version of repository using the same user which works fine over svn+ssh, I get an "Authentication failed" error. On the other hand updating works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: You use the same protocol (svn+ssh) for that checkout on the server? If so first try to ssh-login from the same shell to the address in the svn url. Does that succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bear in mind that if you're accessing through `svn://` it relies on the internal svn authentication tokens for access to the service rather than your ssh credentials.

If I create an svn repository:

```
svnadmin create `pwd`/SVN
svnserve -d --root `pwd`/SVN
```

From another window:

```
svn co svn://127.0.0.1
cd 127.0.0.1
touch foo; svn add foo; svn commit -m'[foo]' foo
```

Yields the error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed
```

whereas:

```
svn co svn+ssh://127.0.0.1/home/pshanahan/SVN FRED
cd FRED
touch foo; svn add foo; svn commit -m'[foo]' foo
```

works without error as it relies on being able to access the repository as a local file.